if my fudge doesn't set up properly can i reheat it?
my fudge didnt get to temp. and it didnt set up properly  I've read that I can add water and reheat it. does this work?

Most probably yes.
You give very little detail here, so we can't know for sure. But in general, fudge is sugar syrup taken to the proper ratio of sugar to water (indicated by its final temperature) and then stirred to harden in fine crystals. This basic mixture of sugar and water can be reheated as desired, and more water can be added to make the reheating easier.
Potential problems can come from the non-base elements. If you added dairy or chocolate, these can brown to a darker consistency than expected, or even burn, on reheating. Also, if you used any flavor essences, these can either evaporate or change their taste in unexpected ways during reheating.
Still, I'd say go for it. You have very little to lose. And even if there is something in there that changes its taste during the reheating process, the result be different than expected, but not necessarily bad. Probably still quite edible and even enjoyable.
